# сортировка в ejs array

Tags: javascript, массивы, ejs

```
<% for(var i=0; i < 15; i++) {%> 
  <li><%= users[i] %></li> 
<% } %>
```

структура users

```
[{id: '15', name: 'Viktor', total_win: 10},
 {id: '16', name: 'Dmitry', total_win: 12},
 {id: '17', name: 'Vlad', total_win: 1}];
```

Как сделать сортировку по значению total_win, от большего к меньшему например?

EJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отсортировать в JS:

```js
var data = [
  {id: '15', name: 'Viktor', total_win: 10},
  {id: '16', name: 'Dmitry', total_win: 12},
  {id: '17', name: 'Vlad', total_win: 1}
];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.total_win < b.total_win;
});

console.log(data);
```

[Embeded JS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) - язык разметки страницы, и его стоит использовать только для генерации страниц, отсылая обработанные данные.